# Pack timestamp in 4 bytes

Tags: c++, timestamp, ctime, time-t, qdatetime

I am very restricted in memory usage.

I need to store a datetime in my program. Precision is one second. Only 4 bytes for one datetime value.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: POSIX time stamp probably, which clocks in 1 second since 1st January 1970 I believe

Comment: Close voted: Question is too broad (opinion based) as it stands!

Comment: @TheOne Too narrow with 32 bits in general! Depends on the precision the OP finally want's to achieve.

Comment: What @TheOne says, but beware the [Y2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

Comment: @MarkRansom What about calculations for dates **before** 1st January 1970. Unlikely to get such _'time stamps'_ of course ... (can't upvote anything right now actually, would have upvoted your comment though!)

Comment: What time interval need to be represented?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the standard uses a signed 32-bit value so you can go back to 1902. Which points out an interesting hack, one way to avoid the Y2038 problem is to use unsigned integers - but then you're left with a Y2106 problem.

Comment: @MarkRansom Well, you're explaining my concerns quite well :) ... I think the OP needs to define a certain point of relation/precision for his _'time stamps'_, to get an appropriate answer ...

Answer (score 4):

Pick the earliest date/time you need to represent and mark that your epoch. Then use a four byte unsigned type as seconds-since-epoch. Be aware this will only give you a ~68 year range but that's all you can get with your restrictions.

Comment: An *unsigned* type will give you up to 4294967295 seconds or 136 years, not 68.